# finding the general solution for a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm practicing for the DE midterm, going through (supposedly) basic questions to practice.

I am now stuck on this question. I am supposed to find the general equation for the given DE. I don't know what I did wrong. I think the approach is correct, but possibly a calculation error? I can't quite figure it out (I've been trying it for at least an hour)

I divided $x^2$ to get rid of the coefficient on $y'$, and then applied Bernoulli's method. Next, I used the intergating factor method since it seemed appropriate to use. Some calculation followed and I got y(x) = C*x^(9/2) - which not an answer.

Can anyone point out where I got it wrong? Sorry for the bad handwriting in advance.
$$x^2y'+2xy=5y^4$$
[image]

Comment: it's done. Hope it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$x^2y'+2xy=5y^4$$
$$x^2\frac{y'}{y^4}+2x\frac{1}{y^3}=5$$
$$x^2\frac{-1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{y^3}\right)'+2x\frac{1}{y^3}=5$$
Obviously the change of function $v=\frac{1}{y^3}$ is better than $v=y^3$.
$$v=\frac{1}{y^3}\quad\text{leads to}\quad -x^2v'+6xv=15$$
which is a linear ODE, easy to solve :
$$v=cx^6+\frac{15}{7x}$$
$$y^3=\frac{1}{cx^6+\frac{15}{7x}}$$

Comment: Hi Jean ! I made a stupid typo ! Cheers.

Comment: Hi Claude ! I didn't see your answer when I was still typing mine. Seeing it now, we agree, +1 for you. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Being almost blind, it is quite difficult to me to read your notes.

From what I can see, you used $y={v^3}$; use instead $y^3=\frac 1v$ and you will arrive to something simple since the equation will become
$$x^2 v'-6 x v+15=0$$

Answer (score 3):

$$x^2y'+2xy=5y^4$$
It's really hard to read the picture ...and to point out where you made mistakes
$$(x^2y)'=\frac {5y^4x^8} {x^8}$$
$$\int \frac {dx^2y}{x^8y^4}=5\int \frac {dx}{x^8}$$
$$\int \frac {dx^2y}{(x^2y)^4}=- \frac {5}{7x^7}+K$$
$$ \frac {1}{3(x^2y)^3}= \frac {5}{7x^7}+K$$
$$ x= y^3(\frac {15}{7}+Cx^7)$$
$$\implies  y^3= \frac x {(\frac {15}{7}+Cx^7)}$$